# Read write barcode data without using barcode scanner device

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, barcode, barcode-printing

I am working on Logistics and package management application. I have already generated bar code in My application. But I have no bar-code device for reading bar code.

Is there any tool for reading Bar code data like QR Code reader. Is possible?

Comment: It is probably possible to write code that can parse an image of a barcode, but unless you have a physical device that captures that image (like a barcode scanner, or a camera), there's no way to solve this using software alone.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I already use a QR code reading  application without any device. So I think it's possible. :(

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the question. If you already have a digital image of the barcode, you can use one of the many libraries out there for extracting barcode data from an image. [Here's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.BarCode/) a popular one that you can add to your project via NuGet. The docs for using it to recognize barcodes from images are [here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/barcodenet/Barcode+Recognition+Basic+Features).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read barcode from `image`. Which is something like

```
private String[] ReadBarcodeFromBitmap(Bitmap _bimapimage)
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap objImage = _bimapimage;
    String[] barcodes = BarcodeScanner.Scan(objImage, BarcodeType.Code39);
    return barcodes;
}
```

see this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/barcode-scanner-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 1):

There are barcode tools which can convert the barcode to text and text to barcode. So we can use our own barcodes for testing purpose. But in case you need reading the barcode only then yes you need to parse the barcode image as mentioned by above

http://www.generator.barcodetools.com/